# Can Github Desktop show a tree for the changes view?

Tags: github-desktop

Is there a way to show the list of file changes in Github Desktop as a tree instead of a flat file list?

Comment: For those who are looking, SourceTree has this feature.

Comment: SourceTree is awesome, but also very buggy. Tower also has a tree view.

Comment: If you are on windows, tortoiseGit has the feature

Answer (score 17):

It seems that that feature was present in v1 of Git for Desktop and it was removed in v2 of the app. There are posts asking for this in 2018 and we still don't have that functionality in 2020.

Source: https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/5468

Comment: That issue is marked as a duplicate of this one https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/1634

Comment: As of 2023 we still don't have this feature... unbelievable

Comment: Well, it's a paid feature in the GitHub web console. This is why they are not going to port it to the GitHub for Desktop client, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

You can try gitkraken for Ui for tree representation instead or inbuilt git plugins in IDEs like intellij or use extensions like git graph in visual studio code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

They won't add it back because they push the paid private repo pricing plan.

[image]